# How to recover from Thunderbird safemode?

Tags: windows-7, thunderbird, safe-mode, addons

Recently, I have updated Thunderbird to the latest version(14.0) on windows 7. And added some add-ons. As it said add-ons are not compatible with the version, I disabled all the add-ons. Since whenever I run Thunderbird a dialog opens:

[image]

I don't see any difference between these 2 options('Make changes and Restart' & 'Continue in Safe Mode').

Each time I need to choose among these buttons. Is there any way to suppress this dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just deleted the extensions folder in the Profile folder of Thunderbird. So window isn't appeared. 
Source: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Uninstalling_extensions